# How to convert a column filled with integer to text format - VBA - Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to convert all data in column B , which currently are integers ex. 26, to text format, ex "26". I have tried the following:

```
Dim index As Long

index = 2

Do While index_5 <> NewResizeRange

   Worksheets("Source").Cells(index, "B").Value = CStr(Worksheets("Source").Cells(index, "B").Value)

   index = index + 1

Loop
```

Which turned to be extremely slow and ineffective.

I also tried:

```
Sub Macro8()

   Columns("E:E").Select
   Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("Table1[[#Headers],[Column5]]"), _
    DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter _
    :=False, Tab:=True, Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, _
    Other:=False, FieldInfo:=Array(1, 2), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
End Sub
```

Problem is that when the data comes from another worksheet and the cell is refering to said worksheet it is only displaying the location of the data in the cell.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does it need to be a VBA solution?

Comment: have you tried to just change the format of the range `.NumberFormat = "@"` ?

Comment: @Nathan_Sav no not really, never seen it before!

Comment: @MrDogme yes, it has to be

Comment: @Nathan_Sav It did not work. A1 = 15 and A1="15" is still givning me false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is this what you looking for?

```
Range("B1:B288889").NumberFormat = "@"
```

Cheers

Elmnas

Comment: Not really because If B2=15 and I use .NumberFormat = "@" then B2="15" is still false. @DanielElmnas

Answer (score 1):

Try this then:

```
Range("D1:D999999").FormulaR1C1 = "=TEXT(RC[-3],""0"")"
Range("D1:D999999").Copy 
Range("A1:A999999").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```